# WebDriver / Sauce Labs / Chai / chai-as-promise Documentation?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, chai, saucelabs

I've got a scenario testing setup going with Sauce Labs, WebDriver, I'm including chai and the chai-as-promise library. I've been pulling bits and pieces out of examples and have got as far as:

```
require('colors');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

var wd = require('wd');
var asserters = wd.asserters;

chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = wd.transferPromiseness;

var browser = wd.promiseChainRemote(
      "ondemand.saucelabs.com", 80, 
      "-------------", 
      "------------------------------");

browser
  .on('status', function(info){
    console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', info.cyan);
  })

  .on('command', function(meth, path, data){
    console.log(' > \x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m: %s', meth.yellow, path.grey, data || '');
  })

  .init({
    browserName: 'chrome', 
    version: '31', 
    platform: 'Mac 10.8', 
    tags: ["test"], 
    name: "Test"
  })
  .
  .
  .
```

but I'm not really sure where to go from here. The ReadMe at https://github.com/admc/wd has a great overview and description of the concepts. I can comb through source files like https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/lib/commands.js to get some ideas. But what I really need is some documentation with a list of all functions available. A few tutorials to do common tests would be nice.

Essentially, are there any helpful resources out there to get me going here?

Thanks.

EDIT:

For example, something simple, checking the length of a list in the dom:

```
.
.
.
.waitForElementByCss('.list-item', asserters.isDisplayed, 2000)
.should.eventually.have.length(10)
```

is giving me the error:

`AssertionError: expected { Object (value, browser) } to have a property 'length'`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Still need help with this?

Comment: Yes. I'm making it work, but any help/direction would be appreciated.